Postscript Timeout?
I have an Okidata C530dn laser printer, about 12 years old.  I used it for years over my (wired) network from Windows, Mac, and Linux with very few problems.
While trying to work out some wireless networking issues with it, I plugged its USB connector into my Ubuntu 22.04 system.  When I print via USB, it prints just fine, but after each job is done, there's a short pause, and then it prints a blank page, and then one that says:
ERROR:
timeout
OFFENDING COMMAND:
timeout
STACK:

I'm guessing that the print processor is sending an additional form feed character, which the printer interprets as the beginning of a new job, and then waits for other Postscript commands.  Are there some configuration things I can tweak that might help with this situation?  I'm a very good Googler, and I've found nothing to help with this.

I'm guessing you're right in thinking some additional characters are sent. However, form feed is not a valid PostScript character, so the printer would either ignore it, or generate a syntax error. Try printing to file and check the end of the file (most PostScript is printable text). You can try adding an EOF character (EOT, hex04) to the end of a job.
